# Access Denied while accessing SharePoint Custom List Using Rest APIs via POSTMAN

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, office365, postman, sharepoint-online

From couple of days, I am trying to access Custom made SharePoint Online List for CRUD Operation with the help of Rest APIs Endpoints using Postman, but all the time i am getting `Access Denied` Response in body.

I have got OAUTH Access Token with the help of Client Id, Client Secret, & Bearer Realm Token. I am also sending Access Token in Header, also i am given FULL-CONTROL Permission level by the SharePoint Admin.

Hope you got my point. Please let me know for any further Issue clarification.

**Note :**
**List of Rest URL Endpoints I can Access are given below** :
`http://YourSite.sharepoint.com/_api/site/rootWeb/webinfos`
`http://YourSite.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists`

**List of Rest URL End-Points I am not able to Access are** :
`http://YourSite.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')`
`http://YourSite.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items`

THANKS IN ADVANCE